# does the ordering of the points in vtkCellArray imply adjacency?

Tags: vtk

I have a closed contour in the form of a polyline. I am accessing the point
through vtkPolyData.GetLines() and iterating through the cells in
vtkCellArray.

I want to calculate the angle bisector at each vertex of the line. Therefore
I need to know the coordinate of V_{i-1}, V_i and V_{i+1}.

In the vtkCellArray, [n0, p_1, p_2,... , p_n0, ... ] , if p_2 comes after
p_1 in the cell , does it mean that p_1 and p_2 are connected together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Just to test your case with `vtkPolyLine`, let's create a `vtkPolyData` with a single `vtkPolyLine` where the last point of the line is same as the first point. We will see that the resultant cell array has the same sequence (i.e. the last and first point are the same.)

```
import vtk as v

pts = v.vtkPoints()
pts.InsertNextPoint(0,0,0)
pts.InsertNextPoint(1,0,0)
pts.InsertNextPoint(2,0,0)
pts.InsertNextPoint(3,0,0)

polyLine = v.vtkPolyLine()
polyLine.GetPointIds().SetNumberOfIds(5)
polyLine.GetPointIds().SetId(0,0)
polyLine.GetPointIds().SetId(1,1)
polyLine.GetPointIds().SetId(2,2)
polyLine.GetPointIds().SetId(3,3)
polyLine.GetPointIds().SetId(4,0)

lines = v.vtkCellArray()
lines.InsertNextCell(polyLine)

pd = v.vtkPolyData()
pd.SetPoints(pts)
pd.SetLines(lines)

wr = v.vtkPolyDataWriter()
wr.SetFileName('Lines.vtk')
wr.SetInputData(pd)
wr.Write()
```

The file `Lines.vtk` contains the following:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 4.2
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 4 float
0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 
3 0 0 
LINES 1 6
5 0 1 2 3 0 # This line has 5 points and last and first point are the same (0)
```